# Published applications in MonoDevelop crash

Tags: c#, .net, monodevelop, gtk#

I made a very simple gtk# 2.0 application in MonoDevelop. When I try running the .exe file in my project's bin folder, or running the application when I create a package, it crashes immediately. The program runs fine if I run it from MonoDevelop, but outside of the IDE it doesn't work. I don't want an installer per say, just the .exe that someone can run.

Comment: @mhutch I'm using Windows 7 to develop the app.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the runtime from default to .net (Where it says Debug / Runtime). It 'll also crash immediately.
The problem I guess lies in a missing gtk# .net install?

http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Other way around. If you have the mono compiler installed (and you have it) you can enter a special command line though mono. Type mono in your application search and use the found Mono xxx command prompt program. In there goto your .exe file (cd /d "C:\YourPath\bin\Debug\") and execute it with mono runtime: mono Your.exe. This would work again, cause it is not .net.